# Puedo sincronizar las publicaciones de mi grupo de facebook de ventas con mi página en wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, facebook, woocommerce

mi duda es la que quiero hacer la siguiente mecánica con wordpress, tengo un grupo de ventas en facebook y en este diferentes usuarios pueden publicar sus cosas, desde hace tiempo tengo una tienda on-line de prueba en wordpress que la verdad tiene un tráfico de 0 jaja, y lo que tengo actualmente es que si alguien publicara un artículo en la página de wordpress esta se sincroniza con la tienda de  de la página de facebbok con la que cree el grupo de ventas...

Esto funciona con "Woocommerce" y "Facebook for WooCommerce"...

Lo quiero es ahora un resultado opuesto, que las publicaciones del grupo puedan ser sincronizadas a la tienda on-line que trabaja con woocommerce, y hablo del grupo, por que la mecánica que tengo actualmente publica los artículos de mi tienda en la página de facebook...

Hay alguna manera, esto es posible?...

Comment: Imagino que tendrás que crear una App en Facebook Developers o entonces conectarte al FB API periodicamente via WP cron job para ver sí hay publicaciones nuevas en el grupo y traer la información

Comment: prueba este plugin https://github.com/tareq1988/fb-group-to-wp ten en cuenta que se vienen cambios en el API asi que puede dejar de funcionar https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

Comment: El plugin me pide un ID de grupo, ese como es, es el numero que aparece en su link de facebook? Probé herramientas on-line para sacars ID, pero solo funcion para mi perfil personal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress tiene una opción para compartir pero hasta ahí, solo pone el link, titulo y parte del contenido así que si quieres una publicación completa no la tendrás. Tendrás que mirar un complemento para ver si existe algo para publicar en la red social.
[Plugins de wordpress de facebook](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/search/facebook/)